# Calculating field based on referencing IDs from other fields using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, streets

I am using ArcGIS Pro and working with street segment data. Each road is defined by multiple sets of beginning and end segments representing intersections and resulting in multiple entries for each road.

The **RoadName** and **RouteID** is defined for each of these entries. There are two attributes called **BeginFeatu** and **EndFeature** that are defined only by their **RouteID** (such as 12345678, 09876543, etc). This makes the data unusable for what my client would like presented. I've created two more attribute names called **SegmentStart** and **SegmentEnd**. I would like to be able to reference **RouteID**'s to calculate the names of the Beginning and End features into Segment Start and End.

The below chart is an approximation to what I'm working with, though my data is much more complete than this.

| RouteID | RoadName | BeginFeatu | EndFeature | SegmentStart | SegmentEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | North St | 456 | 789 |  |  |
| 123 | North St | 789 | 555 |  |  |
| 456 | Maple St | 111 | 222 |  |  |
| 789 | Oak St | 333 | 444 |  |  |
| 555 | Elm St | 666 | 777 |  |  |

What I would like returned is something like this:

| RouteID | RoadName | BeginFeatu | EndFeature | SegmentStart | SegmentEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | North St | 456 | 789 | Maple St | Oak St |
| 123 | North St | 789 | 555 | Oak St | Elm St |
| 456 | Maple St | 111 | 222 |  |  |
| 789 | Oak St | 333 | 444 |  |  |
| 555 | Elm St | 666 | 777 |  |  |

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: You could join the table twice - once by beginFeatu > routeID and once by endFeature > routeID